# SvelteKit: How to use asset paths imported via JSON file?

Tags: svelte, assets, sveltekit

I am trying to build my SvelteKit application for production but I have trouble with using my image assets.

I have got a Json file pointing to all my asset's paths, which I am importing into my Svelte components.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPpup.png) is the error I get.

and I would like to use them as such:

```
<script>
    import Images from "/src/contentrain/Images/Images.json";  
</script>

<div class="hero-items">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-content flex-col lg:flex-row z-20">
            <div class="card bg-base-100 p-10">
                <figure class="px-10 pt-10">
                    <img src={Images[12].Path} draggable="false" alt="img" class="rounded-xl" />
```

Can someone teach me about asset routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not importing the asset directly, Vite will not copy it over to the assets folder upon building.  With an example:

If you don't:

```js
import myImage from "/src/somefolder/myImage.png";
```

Then `myImage.png` will not be in the output folder after building with Vite.

Furthermore, the path changes.  This means that you need a JSON for paths when developing, and another JSON for paths when deploying.

Since you don't want to abandon your `Images.json` file, I suggest that:

1. You move your images to the `static` folder, whose contents should be copied over to the root of your website.
2. You get fancy with your configuration.  You can use [wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config) to create environment-aware configuration objects that will automatically change according to the specified environment.